# Rhino Mock vs debug mode?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

my problem is following:

I have ms unit test which uses stubbed http context for mvc routing tests. But one part of code (which uses rhino mock) is problematic:

```
var httpContextMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
httpContextMock.Stub(c => c.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath)
   .Return(url);
```

In debug mode, second line throws an exception:

[image]

Why such an error occurs ? While tests are fired without debugger, everything works fine.

Regards

Comment: Does your stubbed behavior get correctly called?  Is it returning the correct value?

Comment: In debug mode I cannot check because of the exception. Without debug mode the code seems to work fine. File.AppendAllText(@"c:\debug.txt", httpContextMock.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath) writes correct stubbed values to the file.

Comment: Weird.  I'd expect it to either give that error and not work, or not give that error.

Comment: Post whole unit test code, I suppose an error is in an other place

Comment: An alternative you could try is to abstract out your context/session data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631656/unit-testing-an-action-which-calls-session-object/7631760#7631760

Answer (score 1):

This is really weird. What's strange to me is that your code works in non-debug mode. The `Request` property is not stubbed, so you can't really know what it would return. You may try the following:

```
var httpContextMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
var httpRequestMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
httpContextMock.Stub(c => c.Request).Return(httpRequestMock); 
httpRequestMock.Stub(c => c.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Return(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with mine as well, and fixed it by deleting the `.suo` file for the solution.

I seem to also get different exceptions when toggling the `Break when Common Language Runtime Exception is thrown` setting, which is stored in the `suo` file (Debug Menu -> Exceptions)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your stub method. By using only `.Return()` it will give this value back only *once*. If you don't care about how many times the stub should return the value you should use `.Return().Repeat.Any()`.