# Unit-testing an action which calls session object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How can I unit test a method which uses a session object inside of its body?

Let us say I have the following action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetSearchResultGrid(JqGridParams gridParams, Guid campaignId, string queryItemsString)
{
    var queryItems = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<FilledQueryItem>>(queryItemsString);
    IPageData pageData = gridParams.ToPageData();
    var extraFieldLinker = SessionHandler.CurrentExtraFieldsLinker;
    var searchParams = new SearchParamsModel(extraFieldLinker, queryItems);
    IList<CustomerSearchResultRow> searchResults = null;
    searchResults = _customerService.SearchCustomersByUrlAndCampaign(campaignId,
        searchParams.SearchString,
        searchParams.AddressFilterPredicate,
        pageData);
    return GetGridData<CustomerSearchResultGridDefinition, CustomerSearchResultRow>(searchResults, pageData);
}
```

I made the following unit tests which fails so far because of the session thing:

```
[Test]
public void CanGetSearchResultGrid()
{
    //Initialize
    var mockJqGridParams = new Mock<JqGridParams>();
    var mockPageData = new Mock<IPageData>();
    IPagedList<CustomerSearchResultRow> mockPagedResult = new PagedList<CustomerSearchResultRow>(mockPageData.Object);
    var guid= Guid.NewGuid();
    const string searchString =
        "[{\"Caption\":\"FirstName\",\"ConditionType\":\"contains\",\"Value\":\"d\",\"NextItem\":\"Last\"}]";
    Func<Address,bool> addressFilterPredicate = (x => true);

    //Setup
    mockJqGridParams.Setup(x => x.ToPageData()).Returns(mockPageData.Object);
    _customerService.Setup(x => x.SearchCustomersByUrlAndCampaign(guid, searchString, addressFilterPredicate, mockPageData.Object))
        .Returns(mockPagedResult);

    //Call
    var result = _homeController.GetSearchResultGrid(mockJqGridParams.Object, guid, searchString);

    mockJqGridParams.Verify(x => x.ToPageData(), Times.Once());
    _customerService.Verify(x => x.SearchCustomersByUrlAndCampaign(guid, searchString, addressFilterPredicate, mockPageData.Object)
        , Times.Once());

    //Verify
    Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(result, Is.TypeOf(typeof(JsonResult)));
}
```

And the method from the helper of course:

```
   public static ExtraFieldsLinker CurrentExtraFieldsLinker
    {
        get
        {
            object extraFieldLinker = GetSessionObject(EXTRA_FIELDS_LINKER);
            return extraFieldLinker as ExtraFieldsLinker;
        }
        set { SetSessionObject(EXTRA_FIELDS_LINKER, value); }
    }
```

Comment: Can you Mock the ExtraFieldsLinker?

Comment: How do the GetSessionObject and SetSessionObject method look like? Are they by any chance using `HttpContext.Current` in order to get to the Session? If yes, some refactoring of your code will be necessary to make it unit testable.

Comment: Yes, I am using current HttpContext. What kind of refactoring would you suggest?

Comment: @Hohhi, using `HttpContext` is no problem. Using `HttpContext.Current` is a problem. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved similar issues (use of static data accessors that aren't mock friendly - in particular, `HttpContext.Current`) by wrapping the access in another object, and accessing it through an interface.  You could do something like:

```
pubic interface ISessionData
{
    ExtraFieldsLinker CurrentExtraFieldsLinker { get; set; }
}

public class SessionDataImpl : ISessionData
{
    ExtraFieldsLinker CurrentExtraFieldsLinker
    {
        // Note: this code is somewhat bogus,
        // since I think these are methods of your class.
        // But it illustrates the point.  You'd put all the access here
        get { return (ExtraFieldsLinker)GetSessionObject(EXTRA_FIELDS_LINKER); }
        set { SetSessionObject(EXTRA_FIELDS_LINKER, value); }
    }
}

public class ClassThatContainsYourAction
{
    static ClassThatContainsYourAction()
    {
        SessionData = new SessionDataImpl();
    }

    public static ISessionData SessionData { get; private set; }

    // Making this access very ugly so you don't do it by accident
    public void SetSessionDataForUnitTests(ISessionData sessionData)
    {
        SessionData = sessionData;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetSearchResultGrid(JqGridParams gridParams,
        Guid campaignId, string queryItemsString)
    {
        var queryItems = // ...
        IPageData pageData = // ...

        // Access your shared state only through SessionData
        var extraFieldLinker = SessionData.CurrentExtraFieldsLinker;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Then your unit test can set the `ISessionData` instance to a mock object before calling `GetSearchResultGrid`.

Ideally you'd use a Dependency Injection library at some point, and get rid of the static constructor.

If you can figure out a way to make your `ISessionData` an instanced object instead of static, even better.  Mock object frameworks tend to like to create a new mock type for every test case, and having mocks lying around from previous tests is kind of gross.  I believe session state is going to be global to your session anyway, so you might not have to do anything tricky to make a non-static object work.

Comment: may be marking this action as virtual and over-riding it in a stub is better?

Comment: I like you suggestion but I feel like the controller class- ClassThatContainsYourAction- suffers from testing info

Comment: @Hohhi: Whatever you're most comfortable with.  The idea is to make this code testable to begin with, which either would accomplish.

Comment: @Hohhi: So my sample code is *not* how I'd do it.  I was just trying to demonstrate the concept of the abstraction, not the best code to implement it with.  If you want to know how I'd do it, first make it non-static.  Then look up "dependency injection", in particular, "constructor injection".  Then make the backing field `readonly`, so you *can't* accidentally set it.  And get rid of the public property.  Without a DI framework tho, the code I wrote is pretty close to how I would write it.  It is (intentionally) gross, but it gets the job done, and helps prevent mistakes.